# Converting GeometryField to MultiPolygon using GeoDjango?

Tags: postgis, gdal, geodjango

I am trying to add a bunch of school boundary files into the database.  The boundary files are inconsistent.  They are processed by `DataSource` as either `Polygon`, `MultiPolygon`, or `GeometryCollection`.

Converting `Polygon` into `MultiPolygon` is fairly simple using https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13498, but the conversion does not work for `GeometryCollection`.

```
class School(models.Model):
    boundaries = models.MultiPolygonField()

---

from django.contrib.gis.geos import Polygon, MultiPolygon
from django.contrib.gis.geos.collections import GeometryCollection

ds = DataSource('school_boundaries.aspx')
feature = ds[0][0]
geom_geos = feature.geom.geos
if isinstance(geom_geos, Polygon):
    geom_geos = MultiPolygon(geom_geos)
elif isinstance(geom_geos, GeometryCollection):
    geom_geos = MultiPolygon(GeometryCollection)  #This does not work
school = School(boundaries = geom_geos)
school.save()
```

Is there some way to convert `GeometryField` to `MultiPolygon` in GeoDjango?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a good solution.  This only works if the GeometryCollection is an array of Polygons.  In my case I just had to loop over the Polygons in the GeometryCollection, append each of them to a list, and create a MultiPolygon from the list of Polygons.

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import MultiPolygon
from django.contrib.gis.geos.collections import GeometryCollection

ds = DataSource('school_boundaries.aspx')
feature = ds[0][0]
geom_geos = feature.geom.geos
if isinstance(geom_geos, GeometryCollection):
    poly_list = []
    for poly in geom_geos[0]:
        poly_list.append(poly)
        geom_geos = MultiPolygon(poly_list)
school = School(boundaries = geom_geos)
school.save()
```

Comment: Nice :-) Consider closing the question